# Issue with running a JavaScript function build wih jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
function imageDefer() {
   $('img').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-defer'));
   });
}
```

Now I want to run this function this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    imageDefer();
});
```

Here is my html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-defer="thumbnail.jpg">
```

JavaScript and jQuery code is placed in separate .js file but it does work.

Comment: any errors in console like imaeDefer() not defined?? also if there are in separate files you make sure you import file before any script try to use it

Comment: there is no error in console and .js file is imported properly. All other functions are working properly placed in .js file.

Comment: have you tried placing the function within same files?? if so try placing the function within document.ready() :D

Comment: @RohitS That's exactly what I suggested in my answer :)

Comment: @KobyDouek yea... but i guess that should not be the issue. because it does not matter in first case where function is defined unless its within the scope of calling function..

Comment: @DMP can you share whole piece of code?

Comment: Thank you all for help, the issue was with my editor Brackets, it was not minimizing the .js file properly.

Answer (score 1):

What's actually happening is that you are calling your function when it's outside the `document.ready` scope.

Try declaring you function inside `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function imageDefer() {
        $('img').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-defer'));
    });

    imageDefer();
});
```

Comment: Sorry that was typo, It is not the issue. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me well. I don't see any problem. Make sure that **thumbnail.jpg** exists and make sure that your .js file with code is placed after jQuery api:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="file-with-code.js"></script>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mozkomor05/1b7h3cx2/4/

If it will still not working send screenshot of cosole.